# Bash regex match on JSON structure

Tags: json, regex, bash

I have a JSON structure like this which I've read into a bash variable as a string:

```
{
        "elem1": "val1",
        "THEELEM": "THEVAL",
        "elem3": "val3"
}
```

I want to use regex to match on `"THEELEM": "THEVAL"`. It works if I try individual words, where the JSON is stored in `result` as a string:

```
[[ $result =~ THEVAL ]] && echo "yes"
```

But I want to match on the key-pair like this:

```
[[ $result =~ "THEELEM": "THEVAL" ]] && echo "yes"
```

That gives me syntax issues. I've tried escaping, single-quotes and triple quotes to no avail. Any help appreciated.

Comment: More generally, you should use the `jq` utility to parse JSON in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting works for me.

```
[[ $result =~ '"THEELEM": "THEVAL"' ]] && echo "yes"
```

Note that quoting the pattern disables recognition of special regular expression characters, and just searches for the literal substring. This is not a problem here, since you don't have any wildcards or other non-literal pattern characters. But if you did, you'd have to put the pattern in a variable, as in @noah's answer.

Comment: ...though it's an exact substring match rather than a regex match in this usage mode.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good catch. The man page on my Mac doesn't mention that (although it's true in the implementation), but I found the explanation in the online bash manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable $expr to hold the string you want to match to and then use that for the regex.

```
expr='"THEELEM": "THEVAL"'
[[ $result =~ $expr ]] && echo "yes"
```

Inspired by this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170397/using-bash-regex-match-where-regex-includes-quotes-characters)

Comment: You can't have blanks around `=` in an assignment.